# Gridgain SQL query not working with union all and order by

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, ignite, gridgain

```
SELECT a, b 
FROM "table1".table1 table1 
ORDER BY a DESC

UNION ALL

SELECT a, b 
FROM "table1".table1 table1 
ORDER BY a ASC
```

This query does not work. Individually, union all works and order by works, but does not work when together. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Answered this question on [GridGain forum](https://forums.gridgain.com/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=67&MessageKey=f64418a8-5c4a-4243-9cf4-c3510da27cd8&CommunityKey=05618775-f74d-447d-8015-b9bc8152b818&tab=digestviewer&ReturnUrl=%2Fcommunity-home%2Fdigestviewer%3Ftab%3Ddigestviewer%26CommunityKey%3D05618775-f74d-447d-8015-b9bc8152b818)

This should work:

```
SELECT a, b, b, NULL FROM "table1".table1 table1
UNION ALL
SELECT a, b, NULL, b FROM "table1".table1 table1
ORDER BY 3 DESC, 4 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort in an outer query:

```
select a, b
from (
    select a, b, 0 x from table1
    union all select a, b, 1 from table1
) t
order by
    x,
    case when x = 0 then a end desc,
    case when x = 1 then a end
```

Answer (score 0):

Individual query won't support order by if we are using UNION.
Try to remove order by in separate query and after union they to perform order by then it will work.